# InfoPath 2010 form text wrap issue on my SharePoint site

Tags: infopath, css, modal-dialog, multiline-text-field, form-library

So I have an InfoPath 2010 form with a multi-line textbox that won't wrap text in Firefox or Chrome

the text just continues on the same line. On IE, the text wraps properly.

I've published this form to a form library that I created on my SharePoint 2010 site, and the form opens and submits as it should (`I have it appear in a modal dialog popup window`).

I've searched for solutions, and I've been told to add a content editor web part to the page containing the form and apply a CSS file to that to deal with the text wrap settings.

I'm not sure where this content editor web part would go since I directly published the form to a form library on the site, rather than putting it as a form web part on a page in the site.

Is there a way to directly apply CSS to the form itself?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, here is my solution:

The InfoPath form is being rendered on page such as: http://ServerName/_layouts/FormServer.aspx. This page locates at
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\FormServer.aspx. We need to inject the below CSS code in the header section of the page, to force the textarea automatically wrap regardless.

[image]

Same code to be added into C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\PrinLoader.FormServer.aspx, so that the print view behaves the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using multi-line text boxes and using rich text boxes instead. Those give you the option to wrap text. I wrestled with the same issue you're having and couldn't find a reasonable solution for the multi-line textbox which is why I switched over to the rich text boxes.

[image]